# How to properly set content.Headers.ContentMD5 property using System.Net.Http.HttpClient for Azure Table Storage

Tags: xamarin.forms, httpclient, azure-storage, md5, azure-table-storage

I was using the REST API for Azure Table Storage with `HttpWebRequest` successfully.

Now I’m trying to port an application to the `System.Net.Http.HttpClient Classes.`

For authentication with the sharedKey method the `Content-MD5` header was set with

```
content.Headers.Add("Content-MD5", hashString);
```

This works on UWP with the HttpClient Classes as well, but it doesn’t work for iOS (in the request catched with Fiddler, the value of the Content-MD5 header is empty.

In HttpClient there is now a `content.Headers.ContentMD5` property that shall be used.

However I’m not able to set this property in a way that Fiddler shows me the same value for the Content-MD5 header in an UWP solution.
Here is my code:

```
string contentString = "<some xml content>";

       // alternative hash function working on all platforms
       // byte[] hash = xBrainLab.Security.Cryptography.MD5.GetHash  (contentString);
       // string hashString = xBrainLab.Security.Cryptography.MD5.GetHashString(contentString);

        System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider csp = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();

        var hash = csp.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(contentString));

        var hashString = ByteArrayToString(hash);  // is "AABB88AFD4056C0B8E4FEB6B433D5EE9"

        System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        Uri uri = new Uri("http://woschmi01.table.core.windows.net/Test2018()");
        HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("PUT"), uri);
        var content = new StringContent(contentString);

        // former solution, works on UWP but not on iOS
        content.Headers.Add("Content-MD5", hashString);

        // solution I'm trying to get working:

        // content.Headers.ContentMD5 = hash;                // What has to be taken as content.Headers.ContentMD5 property   ?????


        var response = SendRequest(client, uri, content);


        for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }

//****************************************
async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendRequest(HttpClient client, Uri uri,    StringContent content)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response =  await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
            return response;}

//**************************************       
 static string ByteArrayToString(byte[] ba)
    {
        return BitConverter.ToString(ba).Replace("-", "");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching the solution for many hours and formulating this question i finally found the answer myself:

```
 content.Headers.ContentMD5 =  Convert.FromBase64String(hashString);
```